# Verb for "ceasing to like someone/something"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a verb with the meaning of *ceasing to like something/someone*.

To *dislike* is not fitting here, as it means the opposite of *like*, not going back from liking something to having a neutral opinion about it.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank ____ where you would use this word?

Comment: *Unlike* is a verb these days.

Comment: ... which comes from undoing the action or setting/state of touching/clicking the _like_ button. (For those of us less social media savvy.)

Comment: _fall out of like_

Comment: *Unlike**d***.... if we really must.... ***quit** following* is better. Never having subscribed to anything is best.

Comment: Not mentioned so far: to be over something, fallen out of love with something, moved on from something, lost interest in,

Comment: **go off the boil** works in some cases

Comment: Another common one is "lost interest", I lost interest in her.  They all have slightly different meanings.

Comment: fall out of favor (favour)

Answer (score 23):

The transitive multi word verb (traditionally 'phrasal verb') **go off** works in informal contexts:

> *go off* 1. [phrasal verb] B2
>
> If you go off someone or something, you stop liking them. [British,
> informal]
>
> - "Why have they gone off him now?"—"It could be something he said." [verb + particle + noun]
> - I started to go off the idea. [verb + particle + noun]

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-off)]

...................

Although many synonyms are given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/go-off), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/go%20off) and [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/go%20off), for example, for other senses of 'go off' (depart / explode / sound / take place / go bad), many of them single words, none are offered for this sense. And while [Macmillan](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/go-off) does mention some ... I'll class them as 'related words', none indicates the *fall* from favour.

Comment: *Going off at/on someone* means bawling them out, yelling at them, ripping them a new one, subjecting them to one's verbal wrath or tirade.

Comment: In these parts — what @tchrist said.

Comment: Yes, that's the transitive arguably 3-orthographic-word MWV 'go off at/on' = 'explode at'.

Comment: I don't think I have heard *go off* used in that sense, but yes to *put off* or *turned off*.

Comment: @tchrist She’s gone off him because he went off on her about her always going off with her friends.

Comment: This is in British. But my answer'd just be in American. "informal • North American
stop or discontinue (an action or activity). "**quit** moaning!"" - if it's not a resignation, we generally *quit* things that we like doing. Which is why the real answer is already in the title and why quitting smoking is called ***cessation***, the verb for which is *quit*.

Comment: @tchrist - "going off means yelling".  **So what?**  the phrase "going off" has no connection, in any way, to the phrase "gone off" (as in sour milk) or "gone off" (as in lost interest in a girlfriend).  The phrase "I've gone off her" is completely commonplace in the US, Aus and UK.

Comment: To "go off someone" (or something) is an expression that's quite uncommon, though understandable, to a U.S. audience.  I expect it's standard casual British English, and probably Australian, too.  To "go off **on** someone" is *something else* entirely.

Comment: Worth pointing out that 'went off' in Au means 'was really excellent':  "What didja think of Norm's barbie yest'dy arvo?', "Mate,  It went off!"

Answer (score 21):

In addition to "to go off (something)" as suggested in [Edwin's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/608250/3405) there is also the verb "[to sour on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sour%20on) (something)" which means

> to stop liking or being interested in (something)

It's tagged in that dictionary as "US", and it's probably more common in US English, but as a UK speaker I would certainly understand it.

Answer (score 21):

I like the term **disenchanted**:

> *disenchanted*: no longer happy, pleased, or satisfied: disappointed, dissatisfied

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenchanted)]

Edit: Another word just came to me - **Jaded**

> *Jaded*
> : made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by having or seeing too much of something

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded)]

Comment: similar: *disillusioned*

Comment: Incorrect, disillusioned is to believe that something is what it is not and to find out that after the event. Disenchanted in a form, is to be jaded

Comment: That's the correct definition of *disillusioned*, and one shared by *disenchanted*.  The difference is in how the wrong belief/false impression came to be.  If A had a wrong belief about B **caused by B**, losing that belief is *disenchantment*.  If A had a wrong belief about B **caused by A**, losing that belief is *disillusionment*.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying, but that's cause and effect, not a similarity.

Comment: @RiagoMinota [Merriam-Webster does not agree with you](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disillusion)...

Comment: But it's not a similarity. So i'm not wrong...

Answer (score 9):

I immediately thought of [grow out of [something]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grow-out-of), defined by Cambridge as:

> (STOP LIKING)
>
> to stop having an interest in something or stop doing something as you become older:
>
> > He wants to be a rapper, but I think he'll grow out of it.

[Outgrow](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/outgrow) is used synonymously.

We don't have negative feelings for the things we grow out of, but we don't have the passion that used to be there either — there's usually only nostalgia.

Comment: This is generally for things that you liked due to immaturity, like playing with children's toys. You wouldn't use it if you simply lose interest in something, or have a falling out with a friend.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar that `outgrowing something` is to be used whenyou have matured past its appeal. An example would be outgrowing a genre of video games or novels you liked as a teenager.  However , in the cases where it does fit, there is no better alternative word or phrase. For that reason I am up-voting this.

Comment: How would *to grow out of* be simpler or more precise than *to stop liking* or *to cease liking*?

Answer (score 7):

I am going to throw a very short British oddball since it has not been mentioned and I am Tired/Jaded.

**"Tire of"** (not to be confused with Tyre off) in British English , is a frequent  saying indicating a lack of older interest.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tire-of

> to become bored with someone or something, or to stop enjoying an activity: This is the kind of toy that kids will soon tire of. He never tires of (= he enjoys) playing games on his computer.

For a single word try very obtuse **Satiate** but that's usually used for "no longer a need for" such as, satisfied an appetite for something.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satiate

Answer (score 6):

To ***lose interest*** is to stop finding something interesting. It implies that something previously held your attention (in a positive way) for awhile, but not any longer. It's a fairly neutral way to stop liking something, not implying that you now dislike it, just that it's no longer of interest to you. Several of the other answers here suggest a somewhat more negative view of the thing you stopped liking (that you now actively *dis*like it), but losing interest typically connotes a shift from a positive view to a neutral, rather than negative, view.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to [RigaoMinota's "disenchanted"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/608278/129157); I would suggest **cooled** as a lesser degree of change in attitude and **cooling** the actual process.

> to lose ardor or passion
>
> His anger cooled.

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cooled), 2.2]

IMO, "disenchanted" implies that the person in question started, well, "enchanted"; to my mind, "cooled" doesn't bring that implication.

Comment: Yes; 'cooled towards [a person] / [a suggestion/project ...]' certainly fits.

Answer (score 4):

**Weary** is one possibility. To grow or become weary of something means to tire of it for whatever reason. But it's not very suitable for people.

Answer (score 1):

Gotten over?

I had a Dragonball Z phase, but I've gotten over it and now Chainsawman is my fave anime!

Comment: Gotten over makes it sound like it's a good thing to be past it.

Comment: You should probably get over CSM as well. :P

Comment: lol, it was a lie, I haven't seen CSman, just the banner ad! Never gonna get over DBZ!

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest **[pall](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pall)**

To become tired of, wearied by.

> his humour began to pall on us
> He found that his retirement hobbies began to pall after a couple of years.

It isn't as pointed as dislike, but it does hint at a repetition that no longer satisfies like it once did.